# When is nested initializer_list ambiguous, and why do templates affect its behavior?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, stl, initializer-list

I encountered an interesting behavior where templates seem to affect whether a nested `std::initializer_list` is ambiguous or not. Consider the following example:

```cpp
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T = int>
void constructor_T(std::initializer_list<T> l) {
    std::cout << "constructor_T 1D" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T = int>
void constructor_T(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> ll) {
    std::cout << "constructor_T 2D" << std::endl;
}

void constructor_int(std::initializer_list<int> l) {
    std::cout << "constructor_int 1D" << std::endl;
}

void constructor_int(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>> ll) {
    std::cout << "constructor_int 2D" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    constructor_T({});               // constructor_T 2D, why not ambiguous?
    constructor_T({{}, {}});         // constructor_T 2D, why not ambiguous?
    constructor_T({1, 2, 3, 4});     // constructor_T 1D
    constructor_T({{1, 2}, {3, 4}}); // constructor_T 2D

    constructor_int({});                // ambiguous
    constructor_int({{}, {}});          // ambiguous
    constructor_int({1, 2, 3, 4});      // constructor_int 1D
    constructor_int({{1, 2}, {3, 4}});  // constructor_int 2D

    return 0;
}
```

`constructor_int` is almost the same as `constructor_T` except that `constructor_int` is not templated. The compiler complains about the ambiguity when `constructor_int` is called with empty an initializer list, however, the `constructor_T` works fine.

The error message looks like the following (tested with `clang 7` and `gcc 7.5`):

```cpp
// These are expected errors, the question is why constructor_T({})  
// is not ambiguous.

ambiguous.cpp:28:5: error: call to 'constructor_int' is ambiguous
    constructor_int({});
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ambiguous.cpp:14:6: note: candidate function
void constructor_int(std::initializer_list<int> l) {
     ^
ambiguous.cpp:18:6: note: candidate function
void constructor_int(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>> ll) {
```

Why having a template resolves the ambiguity here?

Comment: My question is, why? Why you need to do that?..

Comment: `{}` is convertible to `int`, but `T` cannot be deduced from it.

Comment: The int case is obvious, no?  `{}` and `{{},{}}` could initialize either.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont your example is not the same, you would need to change `std::initializer_list<int>` to `std::initializer_list<T>`. See this one: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/449adab29f5ba88b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
constructor_int({});                // ambiguous, why?
```

You can construct both an `initializer_list<int>` and `initializer_list<initializer_list<int>>` with `{}`.

```
constructor_int({{}, {}});          // ambiguous, why?
```

You can construct both an `initializer_list<int>` and `initializer_list<initializer_list<int>>` with `{{},{}}`.

Try it with

```
initializer_list<initializer_list<int>> a={{},{}};
initializer_list<int> b={{},{}}; // aka {0,0}
```

So those are boring.  Both could work.

But why does the templates work?

The "more specialized" rule.

When the two templates are valid, only the more specialized one participates in overload resolution.

This is similar to

```
template<class T>
void foo(T);
template<class U>
void foo(U*);
```

when I call

```
foo((void*)0);
```

we get `T=void*` and `U=void`

```
template<class T=void*>
void foo(void*);
template<class U=void>
void foo(void*);
```

both are equally good *overloads* if you ignore the template more-specialized rule.

But because `T` can be any `U*` but `U*` cannot be any `T`, `U*` is more specialized.

So C++ picks `U*`.

The same thing is happening with `initializer_list<initializer_list<T>>` is more specialized than `initializer_list<T>`.

Comment: your example is not the same, you would need to change `std::initializer_list<int>` to `std::initializer_list<T>`, and same for the 2D case. See this one: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/449adab29f5ba88b

Comment: @yixing sorry, fixed.

Comment: thanks, so according to this explanation, is it true that C++ does not resolve non-templated overloaded functions based on the "more specialized" rule? I.e.one could also argue that `initializer_list<initializer_list<int>>` is more specialized than `initializer_list<int>` so `initializer_list<initializer_list<int>>` will be used, where in this case `constructor_int` will work.

Comment: @Yixing "specialized" in C++ is a template thing.  Non templates are not specialized.